# Add git layer on SVN repository to be able to branch locally

Tags: git, svn, tfs, version-control

On a project I will work with, the team is using SVN through TFS (Visual Studio).

I'm not familiar with SVN and the fact there is no "branching". I like to create a branch for each "big task" I have to accomplish inside a project. Doing that I'm able to do my stuff without create pollution in the repo and push to the remote only what I want to.

On SVN, as I understand, we work directly on the "remote" and so there is no place for "local branching".

Is there a way to add a git layer in my SVN working directory (by copying it or not). So I manage everything with GIT and then when I'm ready I can do my SVN stuff to "commit" (I don't even know the term in SVN) my work.

I don't want to push my .git directory in the remote SVN though.

**Is this kind of setup possible / appropriate?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Git-SVN](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

It does exactly what you need, use Git commands to push/pull from Subversion, use git locally to manage local branches.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will go look forward for this tool. I heard about it but I didn't understand it would suit my needs.